# Implementing HID input device with an Atmel AVR32

Tags: usb, avr, atmel, hid

I want to implement a small HID input device using one of the Atmel AVR32 chips ([Atmel AT32UC3B1256](http://www.atmel.com/devices/at32uc3b1256.aspx)). The chip has an on-board USB transceiver, with D+ and D- pins etc.

I've been looking at tutorials from [Patrick Hood-Daniel on Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLE72E4CFE73BD1DE1). Also referring to neat little devices like the [USnooBie](http://www.frank-zhao.com/usnoobie/), where the USB interface is done using software, and only supports USB 1.1.

I want to achieve something like USnooBie, but instead, us an AVR32 chip utilizing the built in USB 2.0 transceiver on the chip.

Are there any instructions available online to aid in this process, getting the basics done?

I've Googled around and finding it a bit difficult to find something in relation to the AVR32 USB transceiver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download Atmel Studio 6 and check out the examples (integrated into the Studio). If I remember correctly there even is an example for HID Devices.
Of course there is a fully implemented USB stack available upon which you can still build upon.
Furthermore, there are examples for various other USB devices (Mass storage, ...)

You might also want to refer to the following application notes:
http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8446.pdf - USB Device (HID Keyboard)
http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8499.pdf - USB Device (Generic)

Comment: Getting Atmel Studio was one of my considerations, but I stopped when I saw the download was about 800Megs. Will resume downloading from my faster connection at home tonight.

Comment: In the meanwhile, you can also check out the documentation: http://asf.atmel.com/docs/latest/common.services.usb.class.hid.device.generic.example.evk1101/html/index.html.

Answer (score 2):

Jan Axelson, the author of [USB Complete](http://www.lvr.com/usbc.htm), has some fantastic HID info and tips on the [lvr website](http://www.lvr.com/usbcode.htm#atmel) (link goes to Atmel bookmark).  I don't know if that addresses AVR32 specifically, but I can't imagine a USB stack hasn't been implemented and made available.  I highly recommend USB Complete, by the way

Answer (score 0):

Also you may checkout [www.beyondlogic.org](http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb1.shtml)